# Update multiple records in an Oracle table in JPQL

Tags: oracle, jpa, sql-update, jpql

Is it possible to update several rows in one JPQL query, using CASE...WHEN...THEN expression and parameters ? It is a table of an Oracle database.

```
Integer param1 = .....;
Integer param2 = .....;
Integer param3 = .....;

Query query = session.createQuery("update NumberEntity i set i.value = case "
        + "when (i.id=1) then ?1"
        + "when (i.id=2) then ?2"
        + "when (i.id=3) then ?3 else 0 end");

query.setParameter(1, param1);
query.setParameter(2, param2);
query.setParameter(3, param3);


@Entity
@Table(name = "Number")
public class NumberEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idNumber", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "value")
private Integer value;

.......
}
```

I obtained this error :
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

The resulting SQL query is  : (I have previously simplified the query, as there are 9 id to distinguish)

```
UPDATE Nombre SET value = CASE  WHEN (idNumber = ?) THEN ? WHEN (idNumber = ?) THEN ? WHEN (idNumber = ?) THEN ? WHEN (idNumber = ?) THEN ? WHEN (idNumber = ?) THEN ? WHEN (idNumber = ?) THEN ? WHEN (idNumber = ?) THEN ? WHEN (idNumber = ?) THEN ? WHEN (idNumber = ?) THEN ? ELSE ? END

bind => [1, null, 2, null, 3, 0, 4, 363, 5, null, 6, null, 7, 0, 8, 57314, 9, 9, 0]
```

I have no char column. But the "value" column is of decimal type, whereas it is an Integer in my Entity. I though I will correct this later. I don’t understand why the error deals with CHAR.

session is an object using javax.persistence package.

Comment: The SQL invoked is ? and the CHAR column is which one? The second query is clearly wrong since the quotes mean the contents is interpreted as a literal, rather than a parameter. What is "session"?

Comment: Please see my edited post

Comment: firstly put brackets around the case in case the SQL processing is confusing itself. Secondly dont set decimal cols to integer, keep consistent to avoid that being the problem

Comment: I couldn't find a correct syntax with brackets either. Changing column type didn't solve the problem. So, I have finally made 9 queries, but I am still interested in the right syntax if someone knows it. Thanks

Comment: define "right syntax" ? What you see there is what SQL your JPA implementation comes up with. A different JPA implementation likely comes up with a different result.

Comment: My JPA implementation is EclipseLink 2.6.0.